# Proper syntax for upsert insert update psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, upsert, parameterized

I have a table that I created in postgresql:

```
> CREATE TABLE issuer(
>     cik                            char(10) NOT null     ,issuer_name                     char(150) NOT NULL    ,trading_symbol                 char(10) NOT
> NULL    ,SIC                            char(6) NOt NULL   
> ,date_added                     timestamp NULL DEFAULT
> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    ,CONSTRAINT issuer_pk PRIMARY key (cik)    );
```

I am trying to either update a row if it exists or insert it if it doesn't.

I have searched the documentation on how to make this work, but  I am baffled by the errors I get.

I have a function that I call

```
io = postgres_update_issuer(con,cur,cik,coname,ticker,'')
```

When I call this function, python calls threading and then quits.
Here is the function I call:

```
 def postgres_update_issuer(conn,cur,issuer_cik,name,ticker,sic):

            sql =   """
            INSERT INTO issuer ( cik,issuer_name,trading_symbol,SIC)
                  VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)
                     ON CONFLICT  (cik)
                     DO UPDATE SET
                        (issuer_name,trading_symbol,SIC )
                        = (EXCLUDED.issuer_name, EXCLUDED.trading_symbol,             EXCLUDED.SIC) 
                     ;"""


            try:
    #                 data = (issuer_cik,name,ticker,sic)
                    cur.execute(sql,(issuer_cik,name,ticker,sic) )
                    return True

            except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
                    print(error)
```

When I change the function to this, I get the couldn't move all fields error message:

```
 def postgres_update_issuer(conn,cur,issuer_cik,name,ticker,sic):

    sql =   """
    INSERT INTO issuer ( cik,issuer_name,trading_symbol,SIC)
          VALUES (%s)
             ON CONFLICT  (cik)
             DO UPDATE SET
                (issuer_name,trading_symbol,SIC )
                = (EXCLUDED.issuer_name, EXCLUDED.trading_symbol,             EXCLUDED.SIC) 
             ;"""


    try:
            data = (issuer_cik,name,ticker,sic)
            cur.execute(sql,(data )
            return True

    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
            print(error)
```

What is the correct way to do this. I am using python 3.6 psycopg2, and postgresql 10